# Word VBA Natural Sorting

Tags: vba, sorting

I want to sort an array, or the Files from a Filesystemobject Folder, the way we'd expect them to be if sorted by a human. What I ultimately am trying to accomplish is a macro that takes images from a folder and inserts them into the word document with text above each one to identify what it represents, here I use steps for a guide and it's crucial that Step 2 come before step 100;

Setting up my test sub;

```
Sub RunTheSortMacro()

Dim i As Long
Dim myArray As Variant

'Set the array
myArray = Array("Step-1", "Step-2", "Step-10", "Step-15", "Step-9", "Step-20", "Step-100", "Step-8", "Step-7")

'myArray variable set to the result of SortArray function
myArray = SortArray(myArray)

'Output the Array through a message box
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    MsgBox myArray(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Then the only/best sort function I found is really only good for numbers;

```
Function SortArray(ArrayIn As Variant)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp

'Sort the Array A-Z
  For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
      If ArrayIn(i) > ArrayIn(j) Then
        SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
        ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
        ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
      End If
    Next j
  Next i

SortArray = ArrayIn

End Function
```

That function returns the array as;
Step-1,
Step-10,
Step-100,
Step-15,
Step-2,
Step-20,
Step-7,
Step-8,
Step-9

but I want;
Step-1,
Step-2,
Step-7,
Step-8,
Step-9,
Step-10,
Step-15,
Step-20,
Step-100

I thought using StrComp(ArrayIn(i), ArrayIn(j), vbBinaryCompare/vbTextCompare) would be one way to go but they seem to sort the same way. If it's easier, I am only going the array route because I couldn't find a way to sort the input files from;

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    For Each image In Folder.Files
        ImagePath = image.Path
        Selection.TypeText Text:=Left(image.Name, Len(image.Name) - 4)
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCr
        'Insert the images into the word document
        Application.Selection.EndKey END_OF_STORY, MOVE_SELECTION
        Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (ImagePath)
        Application.Selection.InsertBreak  'Insert a pagebreak
    Next
```

So I was going to break the file name and path into two arrays that I could sort naturally;

```
    Set objFiles = Folder.Files
    FileCount = objFiles.Count
    ReDim imageNameArray(FileCount)
    ReDim imagePathArray(FileCount)
    icounter = 0
    For Each image In Folder.Files
        imageNameArray(icounter) = (image.Name)
        imagePathArray(icounter) = (image.Path)
        icounter = icounter + 1
    Next
```

but I can't find any reference to natural sorting in VBA.

**Update, Additional Details;**

I didn't think about the A and B after numbers and everything I search agrees on what "natural sorting" is; 1,2,3,A,B,C; Apple < 1A < 1C < 2. Regex might be good
This was how I achieved this in a python script;

```
import os
import re

def tryint(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s

def alphanum_key(s):
    """ Turn a string into a list of string and number chunks.
        "z23a" -> ["z", 23, "a"]
    """
    return [ tryint(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', s) ]

def sort_nicely(l):
    """ Sort the given list in the way that humans expect.
    """
    l.sort(key=alphanum_key)
files = [file for file in os.listdir(".") if (file.lower().endswith('.png')) or (file.lower().endswith('.jpg'))]
files.sort(key=alphanum_key)

for file in sorted(files,key=alphanum_key):
    stepname = file.strip('.jpg')
    print(stepname.strip('.png')
```

For VBA I have found that these;

```
Function SortArray(ArrayIn As Variant)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp1 As String
Dim Temp2 As String
Dim Temp3 As String
Dim Temp4 As String

'Sort the Array A-Z
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
            Temp1 = ArrayIn(i)
            Temp2 = ArrayIn(j)
            Temp3 = onlyDigits(Temp1)
            Temp4 = onlyDigits(Temp2)

            If Val(Temp3) > Val(Temp4) Then
                ArrayIn(j) = Temp1
                ArrayIn(i) = Temp2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
SortArray = ArrayIn

End Function

Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Give me the numerical sort but not the alphabetical, so 1B is sorting before 1A.

Comment: It should suffice if you didn't compare the Array entries directly but rather two temp variables that contain `Replace(ArrayIn(i), "Step-", "")` and `Replace(ArrayIn(j), "Step-", "")`. Then you are comparing the numbers only which should leave you with the desired result.

Comment: I'm wanting it to be more general, "Step-" is the way my images are currently labeled, but they could be "Step " or even include a letter after the number; Step-7a.

Comment: Then you need to provide examples to cover some variants  and also what you would consider “natural sorting” with these variants involved. Maybe a Regex can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to sort Naturally in VBA

Setup/Testing

```
Sub RunTheSortMacro()

Dim i As Long
Dim myArray As Variant

'Set the array
myArray = Array("Step 15B.png", "Cat 3.png", "Step 1.png", "Step 2.png", "Step 15C.png", "Dog 1.png", "Step 10.png", "Step 15A.png", "Step 9.png", "Step 20.png", "Step 100.png", "Step 8.png", "Step 7Beta.png", "Step 7Alpha.png")

'myArray variable set to the result of SortArray function
myArray = SortArray(myArray)

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print myArray(i)
Next


End Sub
```

This is the only function needed to be called in the main part;

```
Function SortArray(ArrayIn As Variant)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp1 As String
Dim Temp2 As String
Dim myRegExp, myRegExp2, Temp3, Temp4, Temp5, Temp6, regExp1_Matches, regExp2_Matches

'Number and what's after the number
Set myRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.pattern = "[0-9][A-Z]"

'Text up to a number or special character
Set myRegExp2 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
myRegExp2.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp2.Global = True
myRegExp2.pattern = "^[A-Z]+"

'Sort by Fisrt Text and number
For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
        Temp1 = ArrayIn(i)
        Temp2 = ArrayIn(j)
        Temp3 = onlyDigits(Temp1)
        Temp4 = onlyDigits(Temp2)
        Set regExp1_Matches = myRegExp2.Execute(Temp1)
        Set regExp2_Matches = myRegExp2.Execute(Temp2)
        If regExp1_Matches.Count = 1 And regExp2_Matches.Count = 1 Then 'eliminates blank/empty strings
        If regExp1_Matches(0) > regExp2_Matches(0) Then
            ArrayIn(j) = Temp1
            ArrayIn(i) = Temp2
        ElseIf regExp1_Matches(0) = regExp2_Matches(0) Then
            If Val(Temp3) > Val(Temp4) Then
                ArrayIn(j) = Temp1
                ArrayIn(i) = Temp2
            End If
        End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'Sort the array again by taking two at a time finds number followed by letters and sorts the two alphabetically, ex 1A, 1B
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To (UBound(ArrayIn) - 1)
        j = i + 1
            Temp1 = ArrayIn(i)
            Temp2 = ArrayIn(j)
            Set regExp1_Matches = myRegExp.Execute(Temp1)
            Set regExp2_Matches = myRegExp.Execute(Temp2)
            If regExp1_Matches.Count = 1 And regExp2_Matches.Count = 1 Then
                If regExp1_Matches(0) > regExp2_Matches(0) Then
                    ArrayIn(j) = Temp1
                    ArrayIn(i) = Temp2
                End If
            End If
    Next i
SortArray = ArrayIn

End Function
```

Found this was useful for the numerical sorting;

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Results

Input:

```
Step 15B.png
Cat 3.png
Step 1.png
Step 2.png
Step 15C.png
Dog 1.png
Step 10.png
Step 15A.png
Step 9.png
Step 20.png
Step 100.png
Step 8.png
Step 7Beta.png
Step 7Alpha.png
```

Output:

```
Cat 3.png
Dog 1.png
Step 1.png
Step 2.png
Step 7Alpha.png
Step 7Beta.png
Step 8.png
Step 9.png
Step 10.png
Step 15A.png
Step 15B.png
Step 15C.png
Step 20.png
Step 100.png
```